# Kotlin: How many items are in range

Tags: kotlin, range

Is there a method that given an IntRange will tell how many items are in the range? I want the result of this, but O(1)

```
var i = 0
for (x in range)  i++
return i
```

--- Edit

I figured out that

range.toList().size

gives the right result, but I'm not sure it will not create a memory problem

Comment: Note that edits to the question should not invalidate existing answers. If you have a new question, please post a new one.

Answer (score 1):

For an `IntRange`, the number of elements is just:

```
range.endInclusive - range.start + 1
```

Note that `IntRange`s can have more elements than `Int.MAX_VALUE`. In such cases, the above will overflow and produce an incorrect number (so will your approach). To avoid this, you can get a `Long` as the result instead:

```
range.endInclusive.toLong() - range.start.toLong() + 1L
```

Comment: What if it is downTo? or it has  a step?

Comment: @ModdyFire Then it'd be of the more general type `IntProgression`, not `IntRange` mentioned in your question.